# Stereo Rectification of two different cameras in OpenCv

Tags: opencv

I have the stereo calibration parameters of two different cameras (different resolutions). I want to use this data for stereo rectification and calculating the disparity map. The problem is that the images from the two cameras have different sizes and I don't know how to specify these sizes. cvStereoRectify takes only a single size, assuming that both the images are of the same size.

Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Khan

Comment: If you add the images and their stereo calibration information, it will make it easier for people answering this problem to verify their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a region of interest on the higher resolution camera? For example, say you have a 640x480 camera and an 800x600 camera. You might do the following:

```
VideoCapture videoLo(LOW), videoHi(HIGH);
Mat loRes, hiRes;

Point hiCenter(hiRes.size().width / 2, hiRes.size().height / 2);

int key = 0;
do
{
    videoLo >> loRes;
    videoHi >> hiRes;

    // this will give you the center 640x480 of the high res image.
    Mat hiResWin(hiRes, Rect(hiCenter.x - loRes.size().width / 2, 
                             hiCenter.y - loRes.size().height / 2,
                             loRes.size().width,
                             loRes.size().height));

    key = waitKey(33);
} while((char)key != 27);
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem once when performing stereo calibration. 
It can be solved by setting the image size parameters

```
    captureR = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );  // from camera 1
    cvSetCaptureProperty(captureR, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(captureR, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    if(!captureR) { printf("\nCouldn't open the camera1\n"); return -1;}
    captureL = cvCreateCameraCapture( 1 ); //from camera 2
    cvSetCaptureProperty(captureL, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(captureL, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    if(!captureL) { printf("\nCouldn't open the camera2\n"); return -1;}
```